# FullCalendar - Different minTime / maxTime for different days

Tags: fullcalendar

Is there a way to set different minTime / maxTime for different days?

eg:
Mon, startTime: 09:00, endTime: 19:00
Tue, startTime: 10:00, endTime: 20:00
...
Sat, startTime: 09:00, endTime: 13:00

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a bit old now, but I was able to achieve this by setting the minTime and maxTime options after initialisation based on certain events. I believe this feature only came available in a later release (I'm using v3.1.0).

In my scenario, when a user clicks on the day, I set the start time and end time based on what day of the week it is. I created a map/dict of the open and close times for each day:

```
// Create a map of the ISO day and the start and end times
// Eg. 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday etc
var openCloseTimes = {
    // Monday
    1: {
        startTime: '09:00:00',
        endTime: '17:00:00'
    },
    // Tuesday
    2: {
        startTime: '09:00:00',
        endTime: '17:00:00'
    },
    // Wednesday
    3: {
        startTime: '09:00:00',
        endTime: '17:00:00'
    },
    // Thursday
    4: {
        startTime: '09:00:00',
        endTime: '17:00:00'
    },
    // Friday
    5: {
        startTime: '09:00:00',
        endTime: '17:00:00'
    },
    // Saturday
    6: {
        startTime: '10:00:00',
        endTime: '16:00:00'
    },
    // Sunday
    7: {
        startTime: '10:00:00',
        endTime: '16:00:00'
    }
}
```

And then in my dayclick function:

```
dayClick: function( date, jsEvent, view) { 

    // Get the day of week integer
    // Eg. 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday
    var dayOfWeek = date.day();

    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('option','minTime', openCloseTimes[dayOfWeek].start_time);
    $('.calendar').fullCalendar('option','maxTime', openCloseTimes[dayOfWeek].end_time);
}
```